# Specific Tensorflow Deps on Raspberry

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, arm64, raspberry-pi4

for a clients AI project I need to install specific tensorflow version and other requirements on a Raspberry Pi.

Can you tell me if it is even possible to get this running or should I try to

1. build everything on the Pi?
   or 2) convert the script and models to tf lite?

```
absl-py==1.4.0
appdirs==1.4.4
astunparse==1.6.3
audioread==3.0.0
cachetools==5.3.1
certifi==2023.5.7
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
colorama==0.4.6
contourpy==1.1.0
cycler==0.11.0
Cython==0.29.35
decorator==5.1.1
filelock==3.12.2
flatbuffers==23.5.26
fonttools==4.40.0
gast==0.4.0
google-auth==2.21.0
google-auth-oauthlib==1.0.0
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.56.0
h5py==3.9.0
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==6.7.0
importlib-resources==5.12.0
Jinja2==3.1.2
joblib==1.3.1
keras==2.13.1
kiwisolver==1.4.4
lapx==0.5.2.post1
lazy_loader==0.3
libclang==16.0.0
librosa==0.10.0.post2
llvmlite==0.40.1
lxml==4.9.3
Markdown==3.4.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
matplotlib==3.7.1
mpmath==1.3.0
msgpack==1.0.5
networkx==3.1
numba==0.57.1
numpy==1.24.3
oauthlib==3.2.2
opencv-contrib-python==4.8.0.74
opt-einsum==3.3.0
packaging==23.1
pandas==2.0.3
Pillow==10.0.0
pooch==1.6.0
protobuf==4.23.4
psutil==5.9.5
pyasn1==0.5.0
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
PyAudio==0.2.13
pycparser==2.21
pyparsing==3.1.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-docx==0.8.11
pytz==2023.3
PyYAML==6.0
requests==2.31.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
resampy==0.4.2
rsa==4.9
scikit-learn==1.3.0
scipy==1.11.1
seaborn==0.12.2
six==1.16.0
sounddevice==0.4.6
soundfile==0.12.1
soxr==0.3.5
SpeechRecognition==3.10.0
supervision==0.11.1
sympy==1.12
tensorboard==2.13.0
tensorboard-data-server==0.7.1
tensorflow==2.13.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.13.0
tensorflow-hub==0.13.0
tensorflow-intel==2.13.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.31.0
termcolor==2.3.0
threadpoolctl==3.1.0
torch==2.0.1
torchvision==0.15.2
tqdm==4.65.0
typing_extensions==4.5.0
tzdata==2023.3
ultralytics==8.0.125
urllib3==1.26.16
Werkzeug==2.3.6
wrapt==1.15.0
zipp==3.15.0
```

After installing the dependencies one by one, my script runs but only until this error:

```
    Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/bin/platforms" ...
loaded library "/home/n3lson/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/n3lson/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.
```

The Pi is running headless, how do I get the required packages?

Thanks for any hint